# How to properly pass struct as argument?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, struct, functions

This is my first question! i'm sorry if i'm doing something wrong.
I'm trying to write a code that blinks some leds, but i cant quite work out how to use structs as arguments.

This is the code:

```
void setup(){
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
  //digitalWrite(2,HIGH); //debugging

}

struct Timer {
  unsigned long DutyCycle;
  unsigned long LastTime;
};


void SwitchPin(int pinn, bool ledstate,Timer timer) {
  if (millis() - timer.LastTime >= timer.DutyCycle) {
    if (ledstate == LOW) {
      ledstate = HIGH;
    } else {
      ledstate = LOW;
    }
    digitalWrite(pinn, ledstate);
  }
}

void loop()
{

}
```

When i try to verify it says:

```
exit status 1
'Timer' has not been declared
```

among other rubish.
I'm very new to programming in general, so probably i'm doing something very wrong without noticing it.
I would be very glad if you can explain exactly what im doing wrong, so i know what to do in the future.

Comment: BTW (regarding your question) : `void SwitchPin(int pinn, bool ledstate, const Timer& timer)` were a better signature for your function.

Comment: I just tried compiling your code - it compiled with no errors.

Comment: i have same problem, what you do for it.